# How to add a class to the <td> in server-side processing mode

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

When using server-side processing on a DataTable, there is a mechanism to add an ID, class, or `data-*` attribute to the table row (`<tr>`) by including the `DT_RowId`, `DT_RowClass` or `DT_RowData` properties, respectively, to the JSON data for each row: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html.

Is there a similar (or any) mechanism for adding additional markup to the table columns (`<td>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add classes to columns like so, but not sure if this gets you where you want to go:

```
     var all_data = data;
     $("#example").DataTable({
            "data": all_data,
      "aoColumns": [{
        "data": 'cat_code',
        "className": "lang_body_2",//you can add whatever you want for a specific column here.
        "visible": false
    }, {
        "data": 'value',
        "searchable": false,
        "width": "20%",
        "className": "lang_body_2",
        "title": ""
    }]
  })
```

Comment: That's it - thanks! Not sure why I didn't find that in the documentation before. In DataTables 1.10, the documentation is here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Comment: @jonmrich Is there any way to add Custom HTML to tds?

Answer (score 3):

Other way, from off. sites [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className).
Assign class my_class to first column

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ]
} );
```